# How to change the default 'admin' username in Apache DS?

Tags: ldap, apacheds

Long story short the security people at my company does not want us to use the default 'admin' username in Apache DS. Is there a way to change it without breaking anything? Also how to create an additional admin account that is a clone of the default 'admin' user? I couldn't find any documentation for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apache Directory Studio to do this:

1. Copy (Ctrl-C) entry uid=admin
2. Paste (Ctrl-V) into ou=system renaming the user entry on the way
3. Select cn=Administrators,ou=groups,ou=system
4. Add a member reference to the new user entry
5. Check you can successfully bind using the new user

Comment: Can you elaborate Step 4.

Comment: Did you mean just add uid=NewAdmin as a new attribute to cn=Administrators?

Comment: seems to be working fine with new admin id. I created and deleted a partition with the new admin account. So I am accepting the answer. But I am not 100% sure if this id has all the permissions as 'admin. Thank you marabu